# Risks per medical treatment

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a data set on risks per medical treatment as many following fields as possible:

- list of risk factors per medical treatment
- some quantification of the risk (e.g., an autologous blood injections to treat a lateral epicondylitis of the humerus carries a 1% chance of injury to structures near the tendon).
- references for each risk (i.e., in which research study medical treatment X was shown to have a risk of y%.)